# vertical center align for anchor inline block

Tags: html, css

How can I align vertically my anchor that is using inline-block?
http://jsfiddle.net/XdfCp/11/

If I change to block, the align works well but the anchor element didn't cover all div.

Comment: I don't understand what's the expected result is.

Comment: The 23 number, in the code above, is on top. I want to align it vertically on center.

Comment: The 23 is already in the middle for me (FF). What browser are you using that it isn't?

Comment: I'm using chrome 19.0.1084.56 m. It isn't here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `padding-top:50%` eg:

```
#ListaEventosPorMes a{
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: White;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #722827;
vertical-align:middle;
**padding-top:50%;**
}
```

Comment: Using `padding-top:50%` fixes it in Chrome for me.

Comment: You removed the `vertical-align` try adding `vertical-align:middle;` back in as well as `padding-top:50%;` and if that still looks a bit weird change `vertical-align:middle;` to `vertical-align:top;`

Comment: Strange. It doesn't work here. Is not on top anymore, but It isn't centered. http://jsfiddle.net/XdfCp/20/ To look this effect collapse the windows width to rise the height of component.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height: 100%` on the link. It will be vertically centered in its container.

Comment: If I remove the height 100% my anchor didn't take all available space, covering the div. the anchor and the wrap div should appear as only one component.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.dia a{vertical-align: middle}
```

This should work.. hope this helps